# ¿Cómo puedo usar la variable state fuera del .then()?

Tags: javascript, fetch

Tengo la siguiente situacion. Hago `fetch` hacia la `API` de github pero ahora necesito tomar de ese `fetch` la variable `state`, la cosa es que así como esta la variable `state` desde el ultimo `if` sale como indefinida. ¿Cómo puedo acceder a ella?

```js
fetch('https://api.github.com/user?access_token=' + access_token, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
  }).then(res => res.json())
  .then(user => {

    var username = user.login;
    var insert;
    var state = false;
    for (insert = 0; insert < res.length; insert++) {

      if (username == res[insert].login) {
        state = true;
      }

    };
  });

if (state) {
  res.json({
    success: true,
    access_token: body.access_token,
    jwt: token
  });
} else {
  res.json({
    success: false
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu problema es que estás declarando la variable `state` dentro del método `then()`, lo que debes hacer es declararla por fuera y asignarle el valor dentro del `then()`

```
var state = null; // La declaras aquí

fetch('https://api.github.com/user?access_token=' + access_token, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
  }).then(res => res.json())
  .then(user => {

    var username = user.login;
    var insert;
    state = false; // Le asignas el valor necesario
    for (insert = 0; insert < res.length; insert++) {

      if (username == res[insert].login) {
        state = true; // Le vuelves a asignar el valor necesario
      }

    };
  });

if (state) { // Aquí ya puedes usarla correctamente
  res.json({
    success: true,
    access_token: body.access_token,
    jwt: token
  });
} else {
  res.json({
    success: false
  });
}
```

Comment: Funciona pero el problema es que afuera vuelve a setearse en false entonces siempre es false

Comment: @SantiagoD'Antuoni declara `state` **en el nivel mas alto en el que la vayas a necesitar**; en ultima instancia, como `window.getFetchState` (por ejemplo, usa el nombre que quieras).

Comment: state la estoy declarando fuera del fetch digamos donde comienza el endpoint de la API, el tema es que como JavaScript es asyncronico supongo sera por eso fuera del .then state vuelve a setearse en false porque fuera del .then esta el var state = false;

Comment: @SantiagoD'Antuoni Esto es muy malo, **no debe hacerse bajo ningún concepto**. La función `fetch` devuelve una promesa, lo que quiere decir que **es una función asíncrona**. Si tu haces esto, **no tendrás nunca la seguridad que** `state` **tenga el valor esperado** y esto es simplemente porque al ser una función asíncrona, **la ejecución de fetch no es bloqueante**, se ejecutará en paralelo al resto de código.

Comment: Si tratas con una función asíncrona, **debes seguir el mismo patrón**. Poe ejemplo, puedes recuperar `state` en un callback pasado a la función que hace el `fetch`; también puedes usar promise chaining o *encadenamiento de promesas* para **devolver la promesa acutal** con `state` ya procesado (como lo indica @amenadiel) o usar async/await.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías retornar state desde la respuesta del fetch como argumento de un nuevo `then`

```
 fetch('https://api.github.com/user?access_token=' + access_token, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
  }).then(res => res.json())
  .then(user => {

    var username = user.login;
    var insert;
    var state = false;
    for (insert = 0; insert < res.length; insert++) {
      if (username == res[insert].login) {
        state = true;
      }

    };
    return state; // <--- lo paso al siguiente then

  }).then(state => {
    if (state) {
      res.json({
        success: true,
        access_token: body.access_token,
        jwt: token
      });
    } else {
      res.json({
        success: false
      });
    }
  });
```

En este caso no tengo idea de dónde salen `token` ni `body`, es específicamente para que tengas acceso a `state`

Answer (score 1):

> **No declares la variable fuera del callback**, ya que `fetch` es una función asíncrona. Por ende, **no tienes ninguna manera de asegurar** que la variable `state` esté disponible al acabar la petición.

Lo que te ha expuesto @Jorius no debes hacerlo bajo ningún concepto. Esta es una causa muy común de problemas cuando tratas con código asíncrono.

> Una ejecución asíncrona es **no bloqueante** lo que quiere decir, que no se ejecuta **secuencialmente**, si no, en una especie de paralelismo.

En pocas palabras, si ejecutas dos funciones asíncronas, la segunda puede resolverse primero. No hay forma de determinar cuál se resolverá primero, salvo por detalles técnicos como latencia, etc.

Para solventar tu problema, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

1. Usar async/await.
2. Usar *promise chaining* para devolver `state` en el `then` (cubierto por @amenadiel).
3. Pasar `state` en un callback.

---

#### Usando async/await

Esta es una nueva característica que llegará este año con ES8 con la que puedes *esperar a que termine* la ejecución de una función asíncrona pero sin ser bloqueante.

```
const response = await (
  fetch('https://api.github.com/user?access_token=' + access_token, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
  });
);

const { login } = await response.json();
let state = false;

for (insert = 0; insert < res.length; insert++) {
  if (username == res[insert].login) {
    state = true;
  }
}

return state;
```

Al ser un código sintácticamente *síncrono*, podrás retornar `state` como en cualquier función.

#### Usando callbacks

Esta es la que siempre se usaba en ES5. No hay mayor misterio, solo se le pasa una función la cual es ejecutada cuando se termine de procesar `state`:

```
.then(user => {
  var username = user.login;
  var insert;
  var state = false;

  for (insert = 0; insert < res.length; insert++) {
    if (username == res[insert].login) {
      state = true;
    }
  }

  cb(state); // aquí le pasamos state al callback
});
```

Entonces, supongamos que la función se llama `getAccessToken`:

```
getAccessToken(state => {
  // state es accesible aquí
});
```